# What happens when you call a function with return value without assigning it to any variable?

Tags: c, function, return-value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f(int x) {
    return x;
}

int main ( int argc,char * argv[]) {
    int a=4;
    f(a);
    printf("PASSED!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

What happens when you call `f(a)` without assigning it to anything?

Comment: nothing, the return value gets ignored. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: The same as writing `10;`.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh like statement with no effect?

Comment: Taking about return value, yes, However, the side-effects of calling the functions will be there, for example, modifying a static variable value.

Comment: "No effect" is wrong. The function may still be called, but the compiler could also choose to optimize out the call if it has no compile-time deductible size-effects.

Comment: Writing `4;` causes the compiler to produce "statement with no effect" warning. But writing writing `f(4)` gives no warning. How come?

Comment: Because of int x argument from f() Function. You specify what value X has.

Comment: @odin19 - A compiler is not required to emit warnings.  There's no C requirement to *use* the result of any statement, and `f(4)` may not be obvious enough to whatever logic the compiler writers used to identify a statement with no effect.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It'd be funny is there *were* such a requirement, considering `a = b` is an expression.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: If the side-effects cannot be deduced at compile-time, the function must **not** be optimised out. Only if the compiler can prove there are no side-effects.

Comment: If you enable recommended warnings on a modern compiler, it should warn. To suppress that warning and show the compiler you ignore the result intentionally in a standard compliant way, cast the result to `void`: `(void)f(a);`.

Comment: BTW: even the `printf("PASSED!\n");` at the end of the program returns an int (which is ignored, too)

Answer (score 6):

> What happens when you call a function with return value without assigning it to any variable?

The return value of a function need not be used or assigned.  It is ignored (usually quietly).

The function still executes and its side effects still occur.

---

Consider the 3 functions: `int scanf()`, `int f()`, and `int printf()`, their return values are all ignored yet the functions were still executed.

```
int a=4;
scanf("%d", &a);
f(a);
printf("PASSED!\n");
```

It is not good to ignore return values in robust code, especially `scanf()`.

---

As commented by [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559547/what-happens-when-you-call-a-function-with-return-value-without-assigning-it-to/35560144#comment58808701_35559547), a warning may be enabled by some compilers.

Explicit ignoring the result of a function is sometime denoted with `(void)` to quiet that warning.

```
(void) f(a);
```

Comment: Why did you say *especially `scanf()`* in "It is not good to ignore return values in robust code, especially scanf()."? You meant the actual `scanf()` function from `stdio.h` library or you meant your custom function i.e. `int scanf()`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Using your example, we can look at how it evaluates line by line. Starting in main.

```
int a=4;
```

We now have a variable *a* with the value 4.

```
f(a);
```

So now the function *f* is called with *a*, which has a value of 4. So in the function *f*, the first parameter is named *x* and it just returns that parameter *x*.

So the evaluation of

```
f(a);
```

is just

```
4;
```

And a program like this compiles and runs perfectly fine.

```
int main(int argv, char *argv[]) {
   1 + 1;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> What happens when you call f(a) without assigning it to anything?

--> Nothing **at all**.

*What happens when you call a function (which has return value) without assigning it to anything?*

-->The function will be executed, either make no sense like your case or make a lot of senses like modifying a static variable or a global variable. The return value will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The *return value* will normally be stored in a register and will not fade.
It will be overwritten when the register is needed by the compiler.

If the function is *inlin*e it may be detected by the compiler that the value isn't used and ignore the value from being computed at all.